# Demystify docker bridge networking

Tags: docker, docker-network

The picture below illustrates my network configuration. I'm spinning up an alpine container per Docker's [bridge network tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/) and playing around with ping/traceroute to try and understand what's going on. Some things I think I understand but some I'm still confused about. Any insights appreciated!
(Hosts here are all Ubuntu machines).
[image: Network Config]

So here are some things I've tried along with my explanations/questions:

- From M1

```
$ ping 172.17.0.2
<no response>
```

I think this is a general routing thing. The packet hits eth0 but then that host doesn't know how to route it to a different subnet. Probably I could make this work with an iptables rule?

- From the Docker host

```
$ traceroute 172.17.0.2
<single hop gets to destination>

$ traceroute -i eth0 172.17.0.2
1 _gateway (192.168.0.1)
2 * * *
...
```

I'm actually not entirely sure that traceroute does with multiple interfaces but maybe it tries them all? The second example kinda makes sense since forcing the packet out that interface hits the gateway but then nothing because we don't have a route back.

- From the Docker Container

```
$ traceroute 192.168.0.10
1 192.168.0.10

$ traceroute <M1's IP>
1 172.17.0.1
2 <M1's IP>

$ traceroute <M2's IP>
1 172.17.0.1
2 <M2's IP>

$ traceroute google.com
1 172.17.0.1
2 192.168.0.1
<bunch of hops out on the internet>
```

So in the first case, why can I reach the docker host in a single hop? Is that because docker0 is a bridge interface to the host?

In the second/third/fourth cases, why does getting to a machine on one of the subnets(or internet) have a hop at docker0 instead of eth0 or eth1?

And for the fourth case, how does that packet know it has to go out eth0? (probably not a Docker question)

Finally, do any of the Docker iptables rules come into play in these scenarios? I think probably the masquerade rule for when a packet from the docker container to local subnets/internet has to come back?